# Rotate an image at 2 different points

Tags: image, rotation

What I'm trying to accomplish is to rotate an image that is already rotating at a different point. So it's a rotation of an image being rotated.

Ex. I have a player I my game that holds a sword in his hands, and the sword rotates with the arms to face the mouse. But now I want the sword to be able to be rotated around ANOTHER point so the sword can swing in the players hands, while also still facing the mouse.

Heres some code:

```
AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();

Trans.rotate(theta);

g2d.setTransform(trans, x, y);
g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
g2d.setTransform(old);
```

That gives one rotation, but I want 2 and I don't know how.

Thanks

Comment: So the arm and sword rotate around the *shoulder*, and then the sword rotates around the *wrist*, is that right? And do you know how to do one rotation, like the first one?

Comment: Yes that's what I want, and I do know how to do a single rotation. Look at this game to kinda get an idea. http://jgames6222.weebly.com/stag-knight-2.html

The way the first sword in this game moves around is what I'm kinda looking for.

Comment: So what's the problem? You know how to do the first rotation, you know how to do the second one, what happens when you try to do one and then the other?

Comment: Well I tried but only a single rotation works. Which ever rotation is set last, that is the one preformed. I don't know how to set multiple rotations.

Comment: Maybe you should show us how you do a rotation.

Comment: Yeah I just edited my post. I'm using AffineTransform.

Comment: Is `(x,y)` the position of the center of rotation (e.g. the shoulder)?

Comment: @Beta yes, or whatever point I desire. I only know and have used the code above for rotation.

Comment: And after you do the rotation around the shoulder, do you have the position of the wrist?